# Prove that $(2n+1)+(2n+3)+\dots +(4n-1) = 3n^2$ by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, self-learning

Note: This is for self study, the book is Elementary analysis by Kenneth. A. Ross

How to prove the following by mathematical induction, I am stuck

[image: My incomplete proof]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
The $P_1$ step is correct. Your $P_{n+1}$ is not. Look at this hint:

$P_{n+1} = P_n - (2n+1) + (4n+1) + (4n+3) = 3n^2 +6n + 3$

This comes from:

$$\overbrace{2n+1 + 2n+3 + \ldots + 4n-1}^{P_n} + 4n+1 + 4n+3$$

$$2n+1 +  \underbrace{2n+3 + \ldots + 4n-1 + 4n+1 + 4n+3}_{P_{n+1}}$$

Comment: Can i know how you arrived at this hint?.

Comment: Sure. Note that you start with $2(n+1)+1 = 2n+3$ so you have to take away the first term in $P_n$ wich is $2n+1$. And then, $P_{n+1}$ ends up with $4(n+1) -1 = 4n + 3$ so you have to add the terms of $4n+1$ and $4n+3$ to $P_n$

Comment: @NagaChaitanyaVellanki look at my edit. It's more clear now.